# peer channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up a sample hyperledger fabric environment with an orderer and 2 peers. I am not using docker approach instead I am running the actual executable itself.

Orderer and 2 peer nodes started successfully. However, channel creation fails with the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Error on the orderer window**

```
> 2017-08-17 07:28:22.338 IST [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN
> 029 Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc =
> context canceled 2017-08-17 07:31:08.044 IST [common/config/channel]
> CommitProposals -> WARN 02a Current configuration has no policy
> '/Channel/Application/Readers', this will likely cause problems in
> production systems 2017-08-17 07:31:08.050 IST [common/config/channel]
> CommitProposals -> WARN 02b Current configuration has no policy
> '/Channel/Application/Writers', this will likely cause problems in
> production systems 2017-08-17 07:31:08.050 IST [common/config/channel]
> CommitProposals -> WARN 02c Current configuration has no policy
> '/Channel/Application/Admins', this will likely cause problems in
> production systems 2017-08-17 07:31:08.051 IST [cauthdsl] func2 ->
> ERRO 02d Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is
> not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown
> authority) for identity
> 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
> 2017-08-17 07:31:08.052 IST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN
> 02e [channel: testing] Rejecting broadcast of config message because
> of error: Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy
> for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach
> implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining 2017-08-17
> 07:31:08.063 IST [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 02f Error
> reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context
> canceled
```

**Value of ORDERER_TLS**

ORDERER_TLS="--tls true--cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sampleconfig/tls/ca.crt"

**Error while creating the channel**

```
node1@ubuntu:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin$ peer channel create $ORDERER_TLS -f /home/node1/Downloads/fabricDeployment-master/testing.tx -c testing -o node1.honda.com:7050 --logging-level DEBUG  -v
2017-08-17 07:28:21.953 IST [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-17 07:28:21.953 IST [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-17 07:28:21.996 IST [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2017-08-17 07:28:22.014 IST [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-17 07:28:22.019 IST [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-17 07:28:22.019 IST [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-17 07:28:22.019 IST [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-17 07:28:22.019 IST [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AF3050A07506565724F726712E7052D...69636174696F6E2F41646D696E731801 
2017-08-17 07:28:22.019 IST [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 63EBD4B3B350685B39A0C8E8E216EFCB3D4C3C82F74B6FA2638D2A7974EB1E74 
2017-08-17 07:28:22.020 IST [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-17 07:28:22.020 IST [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-17 07:28:22.020 IST [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-17 07:28:22.020 IST [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-17 07:28:22.020 IST [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AA6060A1108021A0608BEF0D3CC0522...1A843140B4B661FA8CBCB3170133AC2B 
2017-08-17 07:28:22.020 IST [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: EB039E58FB665150B556394FD464155BBB349CEBB591A578DE402789465EDA84 
Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]

Flags:
  -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.
  -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool such as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
  -t, --timeout int        Channel creation timeout (default 5)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --test.coverprofile string            Done (default "coverage.cov")
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

**Edit Start**

Thank you for your reply Yacovm. I am still facing the same issue. 
In fact, I am using your github code to try this sample. The script was awesome and easy to understand

Let me quickly brief about the current set up I have.

**Environment**
3 nodes running - Ubuntu 16

```
> **Node1 Details** Hostname : node1 Domain name : honda.com User1 : node1 User2 : Admin
> 
> **Node2 Details** Hostname : node2 Domain name : carfax.com User1 : node2 User2 : Admin
> 
> **Node3 Details** Hostname : node3 Domain name : carfax.com User1 : node3 User2 : Admin
```

**Step 1 :**
Downloaded the Fabric source in all 3 machines and ran “make” – Everything was successful

Source is present in the following path : /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric

**Step 2 :**

Downloaded fabricDeployment-master  /home/node1/Downloads/fabricDeployment-master in node1 machine
From node1 machine, 
I am running the following ( I am using the deploy.sh provided in github with slight changes )

```
[[ -z $GOPATH ]] && (echo "Environment variable GOPATH isn't set!"; exit 1)
FABRIC=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
[[ -d "$FABRIC" ]] || (echo "Directory $FABRIC doesn't exist!"; exit 1)
for file in configtxgen peer cryptogen; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && continue
    binary=$FABRIC/build/bin/$file
    [[ ! -f $binary ]] && ( cd $FABRIC ; make $file)
    cp $binary $file && continue
done

for file in configtxgen peer cryptogen; do
    [[ ! -f $file ]] && echo "$file isn't found, aborting!" && exit 1
done

. config.sh

bootPeer=$(echo ${peers} | awk '{print $1}')
anchorPeer=$(echo ${peers} | awk '{print $1}')
PROPAGATEPEERNUM=${PROPAGATEPEERNUM:-3}
i=0
for p in $orderer $peers ; do

        echo "Making Directory structure for $p"
        mkdir -p $p/sampleconfig/crypto
        mkdir -p $p/sampleconfig/tls
        ip=$(getIP $p)
        echo "${p}'s ip address is ${ip}"
        orgLeader=false
        bootstrap=$anchorPeer:7051
        if [[ $i -eq 1 ]];then
                orgLeader=true
        fi
        (( i += 1 ))
        echo "Creating core.yaml from core.yaml.template for $p"
        cat core.yaml.template | sed "s/PROPAGATEPEERNUM/${PROPAGATEPEERNUM}/ ; s/PEERID/$p/ ; s/ADDRESS/$p/ ; s/ORGLEADER/$orgLeader/ ; s/BOOTSTRAP/$bootPeer:7051/ ; s/TLS_CERT/$p.carfax.com-cert.pem/" > $p/sampleconfig/core.yaml
done

        echo "Creating configtx.yaml from configtx.yaml.template with ANCHOR_PEER_IP & ORDERER_IP"

cat configtx.yaml.template | sed "s/ANCHOR_PEER_IP/$anchorpeer/ ; s/ORDERER_IP/$orderer/" > configtx.yaml


        echo "Creating crypto-config.yml from crypto-config.yml.template with ORDERER_IP and adding hostname node2 & node3"


cat crypto-config.yml.template | sed "s/ORDERER_IP/$orderer/" > crypto-config.yml
for p in $peers ; do
    echo "        - Hostname: $p" >> crypto-config.yml
done
cat << EOF >> crypto-config.yml
    Users:
      Count: 1
EOF

./cryptogen generate --config crypto-config.yml
./configtxgen -profile Genesis -outputBlock genesis.block  -channelID system
./configtxgen -profile Channels -outputCreateChannelTx yacov.tx -channelID yacov
./configtxgen -profile Channels -outputAnchorPeersUpdate OrdererOrganchors.tx -channelID yacov -asOrg PeerOrg

mv genesis.block node1/sampleconfig/
cp orderer.yaml node1/sampleconfig/
cp -r crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/honda.com/orderers/node1.honda.com/msp/* node1/sampleconfig/crypto
cp -r crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/honda.com/orderers/node1.honda.com/tls/* node1/sampleconfig/tls

cp -r crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/peers/node2.carfax.com/msp/* node2/sampleconfig/crypto
cp -r crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/peers/node2.carfax.com/tls/* node2/sampleconfig/tls/

cp -r crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/peers/node3.carfax.com/msp/* node3/sampleconfig/crypto
cp -r crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/peers/node3.carfax.com/tls/* node3/sampleconfig/tls/

echo "Deploying configuration - Moving configurations to respective machines"
scp -r node1/sampleconfig/* node1@node1:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sampleconfig/
scp -r node2/sampleconfig/* node2@node2:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sampleconfig/
scp -r node3/sampleconfig/* node3@node3:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sampleconfig/
```

**Step 3 :**

Resulting crypto-config.yaml

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Org0
    Domain: honda.com
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: carfax.com
        - Hostname: node2
        - Hostname: node3
    Users:
      Count: 1

Resulting crypto-config.yaml
Profiles:
    Genesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
             SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *PeerOrg
    Channels:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *PeerOrg
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererOrg
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/honda.com/msp
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
    - &PeerOrg
        Name: PeerOrg
        ID: PeerOrg
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/msp
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: node2
              Port: 7051

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - node1:7050
    BatchTimeout: 1ms
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    MaxChannels: 0

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefault
```

s

**Step 4 :**
Starting orderer from node1 as node1 user
Starting peer1 from node2 as node2 user
Starting peer2 from node3 as node3 user

Till here things work fine

**Step 5 : Channel Creation**

From node1 as node1 user, running the following commands

node1@ubuntu:~/Downloads/fabricDeployment-master$ pwd

```
/home/node1/Downloads/fabricDeployment-master

export FABRIC=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
export ORDERER_TLS="--tls true --cafile `pwd`/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/honda.com/orderers/node1.honda.com/tls/ca.crt"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=`pwd`/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/peers/node2.carfax.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=`pwd`/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/users/Admin@carfax.com/msp 
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=PeerOrg 
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin/peer channel create $ORDERER_TLS -f yacov.tx  -c yacov -o node1:7050
```

**Contents of configtx.yaml**

```
---
Profiles:

    Genesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
             SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *PeerOrg
    Channels:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *PeerOrg

Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg

        ID: OrdererOrg

        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/honda.com/msp

        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN


    - &PeerOrg
        Name: PeerOrg

        ID: PeerOrg

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/carfax.com/msp

        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN


        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: 
              Port: 7051


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - node1:7050

    BatchTimeout: 1ms

    BatchSize:

        MaxMessageCount: 10

        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    MaxChannels: 0

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:
```

**Output of command line statements when executing Genesis Block**

```
2017-08-18 16:50:37.015 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
```

2017-08-18 16:50:37.175 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 002 Generating genesis block
2017-08-18 16:50:37.179 IST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 003 Writing genesis block

**Output of Genesis Block**

```
 <1.{��������G<&�����n��ix*s!�0
�0
�0
t
����"system*@d6a8b389f09cd34562dda9af564c11bd28fed0ae9c42070f11a56c678b19e704h�N�b����S���>%��_bٮ�/
�/�/�

Consortiums��
SampleConsortium��
PeerOrg��
MSP���
PeerOrg�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
B
SHA2SHA256J�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Admins"1
Admins'

PeerOrgAdmins"0
Readers%

PeerOrgAdmins"0
Writers%

PeerOrgAdmins*Admins@
ChannelCreationPolicy'

Admins/Channel/Orderer/Admins*/Channel/Orderer/Admins"
AdminsAdmins*/Channel/Orderer/Admins�
Orderer��

OrdererOrg��
MSP���

OrdererOrg�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICJzCCAc6gAwIBAgIRAIMBXTi8vzqOVhQiXB+ovQMwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwZTEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG
cmFuY2lzY28xEjAQBgNVBAoTCWhvbmRhLmNvbTEVMBMGA1UEAxMMY2EuaG9uZGEu
Y29tMB4XDTE3MDgxODExMjAzNloXDTI3MDgxNjExMjAzNlowZTELMAkGA1UEBhMC
VVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28x
EjAQBgNVBAoTCWhvbmRhLmNvbTEVMBMGA1UEAxMMY2EuaG9uZGEuY29tMFkwEwYH
KoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEm3VY12jlinzimYav4K39anZGIyd7DrygL7fV
b57S7tpvwTXWfGNt58tDBf584w1Bw7Yr6M3unJjWfNj7VaLwd6NfMF0wDgYDVR0P
AQH/BAQDAgGmMA8GA1UdJQQIMAYGBFUdJQAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zApBgNV
HQ4EIgQgMfMrGCUNqJqCehc2xsAYVyWqVTV3jYDcnmkyBhtFSGcwCgYIKoZIzj0E
AwIDRwAwRAIgMrdpDfMnULyS2dMtjfdWGAXPxDj4URM0nelcSjOpmAoCIB24mFvn
C34fP8icL0QVIOf+mPin2jD4HgsDP58dDFtu
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
B
SHA2SHA256J�-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Admins"4
Admins*

OrdererOrgAdmins"3
Readers(


OrdererOrgAdmins"3
Writers(


OrdererOrgAdmins*Admins!
ConsensusType
soloAdmins"
    BatchSize

���1�� Admins

BatchTimeout
1msAdmins
ChannelRestrictionsAdmins"*
ockValidation
WritersAdmins""
aders
ReadersAdmins""
iters
WritersAdmins""
Admins

AdminsAdmins*Admins&
HashingAlgorithm
SHA256Admins-
BlockDataHashingStructure����Admins;
OrdererAddresses'


node1:7050/Channel/Orderer/Admins""
aders
ReadersAdmins""
iters
WritersAdmins""
Admins

AdminsAdmins*Admins
```

Comment: Comments from [here](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3436?focusedCommentId=28700&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-28700) suggest it might be related to signer

Comment: Ayushya, thank you . I checked the post but I am not able to figure out where it is going wrong

Comment: @Deepa I understand that you have solved the problem. As you said in the beginning, "I am not using docker approach instead I am running the actual executable itself.", when you run the executable: it generates all the crypto material and the channel. So, you were duplicating the execution. Because of that you had the mentioned error.

Comment: @sun were able to solve this error? Can you please share your approach on how you were able to resolve this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

This *usually* indicates that the signer of the channel creation transaction does not have admin rights for one of the consortium orgs, however, it may indicate a failure for a number of other reasons.

Unfortunately, the error must be somewhat cryptic, to avoid leaking information about consortium or channel membership.  To get the underlying cause, you will need to check the orderer logs.  If it is not already set, you will want to turn the log level up to `debug` in `orderer.yaml` or alternately  by setting `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug` (or for versions of Fabric prior to v1.4.x `ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug`) before starting the orderer.  In your orderer logs, you will see the same error text as output by the peer client, but in the preceding lines you will see additional causes for your error.

The most common reasons are:

1. The identity is not in the list of admins for the org.
2. The identity's certificate is not validly signed by the org CA chain.
3. The identity's org is not known to the orderer.

Some other unlikely possibilities because you are using the peer binary and not custom code:

4. The signature does not match the identity or signed bytes.
5. The identity is malformed.

Assuming that the cause is not obvious from the orderer logs, if you post them here, I'd be happy to help diagnose them.

Oh, and as a helpful tip.  You may see a more human readable version of your genesisblock by using `configtxgen -inspectBlock <genesis.block>`.

Edit:  Looking back a the top of your post I see this output in the orderer log:

> ERRO 02d Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is
> not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown
> authority) for identity

This would indicate that the certificate claims to be issued by a CA, but is not signed by the CA the orderer knows about (error type 2 above).  This would commonly happen if you bootstrapped the orderer, then regenerated the crypto material for your environment without removing the orderer's storage directory.

It's important to remember that the `ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPFILE` (or prior to v2.0.0 `ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE`) is only read if the system is not already bootstrapped, so changing the genesis block for the orderer will have no affect unless the orderer storage is also deleted.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your valuable inputs. I have added orderer log information with debug information. Let me know if you could diagnose the problem

Comment: As indicated in my edited post above, the underlying problem seems to be here:

> 2017-08-20 17:54:19.392 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> ERRO 181 Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity

This would imply that the crypto material inside the genesis block does not match the crypto material used to sign the transaction.  Usually this occurs when crypto is regenerated, but the orderer ledger is not removed.

Comment: Thank you Jason. There were two crypto material generated (in my case) and the program was referring to the relative path. Once I used absolute path and pointed it to right crypto, everything worked like a charm !!

Comment: Hello i am getting similar issue. but i think its related to identity not being there in the list for the orgs.
because in the logs i get are 
DEBU 14d Checking if identity satisfies ADMIN role for Org1MSP
2017-11-13 05:44:13.330 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 14e 0xc4201112b8 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: This identity is not an admin 

**how to make an identity admin**

Comment: I had same issue, orderer was not taking the generated msp and was starting its own msp .... :(  at channel creation, it was failing

Comment: If you're getting this error after attempting to delete a network and starting over, in addition to `docker stop` and `docker rm`, you need to run **`docker volume prune`** to remove the old volumes and the associated data (old certs, etc.) ***before starting the new network***.  Your volumes should be named something like `byfn_orderer.example.com`, and therefore can be reused if a container is later started with the same name - and then your new certs will not be used in the containers.  Also be sure that your docker image was not committed with new data (might need to download fresh images)

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with TLS, since the request has reached the orderer.
Have it been a TLS issue - you wouln't have gotten the following error:

> Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Error authorizing update:
>   Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application
>   not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies,
>   required 1 remaining

Now, the error basically means that you tried to send a transaction for channel creation, but the transaction was signed by a user (a client certificate) that isn't a channel admin.

You need to prefix the command with something similar to [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/first-network/scripts/script.sh#L35-L36):

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
```

Comment: Thank you Yacovm, still I am facing the same problem. I have provided additional information about my setup. Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: Please add the configtx.yaml generated from the script, and the output of configtxgen --outputBlock genesis.block

Comment: added the requested contents. Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me.

Go inside your peer docker container. Go to `/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp` and run `export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$PWD`

Run your `peer channel create` command again with appropriate flags.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was some missing entries in the docker-compose file for orderer:

`ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]` was changed to `ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerORG1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerORG2/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerORG3/tls/ca.crt]` and then it worked.

so that's something you might want to check, especially if you have a customized setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the only thing that was missing was to define the `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` correctly.
Using fabric 1.1
Hope it will help others.