# Create Channel failed in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

When I run the e2e-2Orgs demo in fabric-sdk-java-master, everything seemed ok. 
**docker-compose.yaml:**

```html
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

services:
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca${IMAGE_TAG_FABRIC_CA}
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -n ca0 --registry.maxenrollments -1 --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/fcf776b02a05600408d0be9d9752afc59f64950b721cacb363b5b95a0fea6216_sk -b admin:adminpw ${ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_INTEGRATIONTESTS_CA_TLS} --tls.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --tls.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/fcf776b02a05600408d0be9d9752afc59f64950b721cacb363b5b95a0fea6216_sk -d'
    volumes:
      - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config:ro
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca${IMAGE_TAG_FABRIC_CA}
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --registry.maxenrollments -1 --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/b59bba37975dafcc4a93984aa01d3d29b64894617db9e0c9a2d486b5273cbd27_sk -b admin:adminpw ${ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_INTEGRATIONTESTS_CA_TLS} --tls.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --tls.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/b59bba37975dafcc4a93984aa01d3d29b64894617db9e0c9a2d486b5273cbd27_sk -d'
    volumes:
      - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config:ro
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2


  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer${IMAGE_TAG_FABRIC}
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/orderer.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=${ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_INTEGRATIONTESTS_TLS}
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
#      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0Org1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1Org1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0Org2/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/msp/peer1Org2/tls/ca.crt]
      - GRPC_TRACE=all=true,
      - GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
     - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel:/etc/hyperledger/configtx:ro
     - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer:ro
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base/peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
#      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer:ro
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base/peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
#      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
    volumes:
         - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
         - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer:ro
    ports:
       - 7056:7051
       - 7058:7053
    depends_on:
       - orderer.example.com
       - peer0.org1.example.com

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base/peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
#      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer:ro
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base/peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:8051
#      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
    volumes:
         - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
         - ./e2e-2Orgs/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer:ro
    ports:
       - 8056:7051
       - 8058:7053
    depends_on:
       - orderer.example.com
       - peer0.org2.example.com

  configtxlator:
      image: hyperledger/fabric-tools${IMAGE_TAG_FABRIC}
      ports:
        - "7059:7059"
      command: /usr/local/bin/configtxlator start
      container_name: configtxlator

  ccenv:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv${IMAGE_TAG_FABRIC}
```

configtx.yaml:

```html
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2

################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:
```

**crypto-config.yaml:**

```html
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
    # configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
    #
    # Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
    #   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
    #   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
    #                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
    #
    #                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
    #
    #                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
    #                 Org.Domain, respectively.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Specs:
    #   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.org1.example.com"
    #     CommonName: foo27.org5.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
    #   - Hostname: bar
    #   - Hostname: baz

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Template"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Allows for the definition of 1 or more hosts that are created sequentially
    # from a template. By default, this looks like "peer%d" from 0 to Count-1.
    # You may override the number of nodes (Count), the starting index (Start)
    # or the template used to construct the name (Hostname).
    #
    # Note: Template and Specs are not mutually exclusive.  You may define both
    # sections and the aggregate nodes will be created for you.  Take care with
    # name collisions
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Template:
      Count: 2
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org2: See "Org1" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

**fabric.sh:**

```html
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
# simple batch script making it easier to cleanup and start a relatively fresh fabric env.

if [ ! -e "docker-compose.yaml" ];then
  echo "docker-compose.yaml not found."
  exit 8
fi

ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_VERSION=${ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_VERSION:-}

function clean(){

  rm -rf /var/hyperledger/*

  if [ -e "/tmp/HFCSampletest.properties" ];then
    rm -f "/tmp/HFCSampletest.properties"
  fi

  lines=`docker ps -a | grep 'dev-peer' | wc -l`

  if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
    docker ps -a | grep 'dev-peer' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm -f
  fi

  lines=`docker images | grep 'dev-peer' | grep 'dev-peer' | wc -l`
  if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
    docker images | grep 'dev-peer' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rmi -f
  fi

}

function up(){

  if [ "$ORG_HYPERLEDGER_FABRIC_SDKTEST_VERSION" == "1.0.0" ]; then
    docker-compose up --force-recreate ca0 ca1 peer1.org1.example.com peer1.org2.example.com ccenv
  else
    docker-compose up --force-recreate
fi

}

function down(){
  docker-compose down;
}

function stop (){
  docker-compose stop;
}

function start (){
  docker-compose start;
}


for opt in "$@"
do

    case "$opt" in
        up)
            up
            ;;
        down)
            down
            ;;
        stop)
            stop
            ;;
        start)
            start
            ;;
        clean)
            clean
            ;;
        restart)
            down
            clean
            up
            ;;

        *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {up|down|start|stop|clean|restart}"
            exit 1

esac
done
```

But when I recreate Certificates and other cryptography artifacts by command : cryptogen generate --config crypto-config.yaml --output=crypto-config , modified docker-compose.yaml , started up the network and created channel again. It failed to create Channel and printed some Error Messages in Command Line:

```html
[33morderer.example.com       |[0m [31m2018-02-19 13:21:08.393 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> ERRO 1b3[0m Principal deserialization failure (The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")) for identity 0a074....
```

I don't know how to fix it. I have tried to remove all the containers and restart docker again, it still did not work. And I tried solutions in [peer channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726536/peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric)

And it also didn't work.

Comment: Did you tear down the running docker containers from the initial run? If not, you'll get this message because the crypto material you generated initially is what the running containers contain. However, the CLI container which submits the create channel proposal will have stopped (it times out) and so it will contain the newly generated material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you recreate your crypto material, you will need to replace the secret key of the CA File

--ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/**fcf776b02a05600408d0be9d9752afc59f64950b721cacb363b5b95a0fea6216_sk**

You can find it under ‘/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/’.

CA in my compose file:

```
ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0a2f532c1e8cb914e9b6c7b56769081bbb7a8b295921bc6fc84464d9aec3e394_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0a2f532c1e8cb914e9b6c7b56769081bbb7a8b295921bc6fc84464d9aec3e394_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
```

Comment: When I finished recreating my crypto material, I modified the file---docker-compose.yaml and changed what you mentioned. It still did not work. By the way, if you didn't modify it, docker container ca_peerOrg1 and ca_peerOrg2 would not be started.

Comment: could you look up to your ca log "docker logs container_id"?
just to make sure there was no error in the startup. if there is a key mismatch issue, the CA will start but won't serve the communication

Comment: I checked ca_peerOrg1 and ca_peerOrg2 logs, and there were no errors.

Comment: also, I have added CA template above in the answer. It has few variables that are missing in your compose file. But I believe since there was no error in the logs. so we might need to think in the different direction

Comment: I have fixed it. Configuration blockchain network was not the right reason. And blockchain operated correctly. I used the wrong channel dir path in my client program code. And when I started up the blockchain network by client, it could not create channel correctly.