# "Principal deserialization failure" when attempting to register a new channel on my blank hyperledger network

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to set up a kafka based hyperledger configuration with a single organization.

I have a working docker network that allows the containers to communicate. The kafka/zookeeper setup also seems to be working fine; orderer logs and recognizes all four kafka nodes. The issue I'm having occurs when trying to create a new channel on an otherwise blank setup.

The commands I run to bootstrap the network are:

```
cryptogen generate --config=crypto-config.yaml

configtxgen -profile MyFakeOrgGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block


configtxgen -profile Channel1 -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel1.tx -channelID channel1

configtxgen -profile Channel2 -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel2.tx -channelID channel2

# has to be done to update the CA certificate filename

SK_FILE=$(basename $(ls ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/ca/*_sk))                                                                                                                 

sed -i "s#FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/.*#FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/$SK_FILE#" dockers/docker-compose.yml


docker-compose -f dockers/kafka-compose.yml up -d       
docker-compose -f dockers/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Then, inside the cli contrainer, I run:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.myfakeorg.si:7050 channel1 -f /etc/hyperledger/channel-artifacts/channel1.tx --cafile $PWD/crypto/ordererOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.myfakeorg.si-cert.pem  -c channel1
```

This invariably fails with:

```
2018-05-03 12:34:56.518 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP                                                                                                                                                        
2018-05-03 12:34:56.518 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-03 12:34:56.529 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized                                                                                                                              
2018-05-03 12:34:56.529 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP                                                                                                                                                        
2018-05-03 12:34:56.531 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity                                                                                                                                    
2018-05-03 12:34:56.532 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP                                                                                                                                                        
2018-05-03 12:34:56.532 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity                                                                                                                                    
2018-05-03 12:34:56.532 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AFE050A084C756369734D535012F105...0A0E47445052436F6E736F727469756D                                                                                              
2018-05-03 12:34:56.533 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: CBAC9B6A3A06426802DFB81D1196DCF28534A52BA369095151BE6DB954A6A7E3                                                                                                    
2018-05-03 12:34:56.534 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP                                                                                                                                                        
2018-05-03 12:34:56.534 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity                                                                                                                                    
2018-05-03 12:34:56.534 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP                                                                                                                                                        
2018-05-03 12:34:56.534 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-03 12:34:56.535 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AB4060A1408021A0608F083ACD70522...C96F9F62C4F53749F47ECFC3A16F88F4 
2018-05-03 12:34:56.535 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: 388F95E877FB3442AA20001CC212777DB2BC38F70799B9D463C19488B64C2B77 
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

As these errors are purposefully vague, as [another answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726536/peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric), heres the parallel log from the orderer container:

```
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 158 Manager Channel looking up path []
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 159 Manager Channel has managers Application
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 15a Manager Channel has managers Orderer
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 15b Manager Channel looking up path [Application]
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 15c Manager Channel has managers Application
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 15d Manager Channel has managers Orderer
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 15e Manager Channel/Application looking up path []
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Manager -> DEBU 15f Manager Channel/Application has managers MyFakeOrg
2018-05-03 11:56:41.344 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 160 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy ==
2018-05-03 11:56:41.345 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 161 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2018-05-03 11:56:41.345 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 162 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/MyFakeOrg/Admins ==
2018-05-03 11:56:41.345 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 163 Obtaining identity
2018-05-03 11:56:41.345 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 164 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 165 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.myfakeorg.si")) for identity 0a084c756369734d535012f1052d2d2d2d2d424547494e2043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a4d49494341444343416165674177494241674951482b4d7033506d6d636459635a6f4e3858726943616a414b42676771686b6a4f50515144416a426a4d5173770a435159445651514745774a56557a45544d4245474131554543424d4b5132467361575a76636d3570595445574d4251474131554542784d4e5532467549455a790a5957356a61584e6a627a45524d4138474131554543684d496248566a61584d7563326b784644415342674e5642414d5443324e684c6d783159326c7a4c6e4e700a4d423458445445344d4455774d7a45784e54417a4d566f58445449344d44517a4d4445784e54417a4d566f77557a454c4d416b474131554542684d4356564d780a457a415242674e5642416754436b4e6862476c6d62334a7561574578466a415542674e564241635444564e6862694247636d467559326c7a59323878467a41560a42674e5642414d4d446b466b62576c755147783159326c7a4c6e4e704d466b77457759484b6f5a497a6a3043415159494b6f5a497a6a304441516344516741450a4c73573137542b2f507051677731384179314176503755417a6771363953793777623147656e6a6c644c5939486c3874374d6873494642624c466b4b6d464e740a4334367937477a51784538692b304d6d4c45485134714e4e4d45737744675944565230504151482f42415144416765414d41774741315564457745422f7751430a4d4141774b7759445652306a42435177496f41674d76744a4b565a44627578473059736a676350454c2f5663443965464673486a5a30305976512f72376363770a436759494b6f5a497a6a3045417749445277417752414967427a3153792b58464f714f376a76397155683671384b506b486e6d744e75335275324533734d48470a72476f4349486d397766774b356a6d3262735a5576594e765630536b6368327377653746632b45426c77517356624b520a2d2d2d2d2d454e442043455254494649434154452d2d2d2d2d0a
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 166 0xc42000ee48 gate 1525348601346256695 evaluation starts
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 167 0xc42000ee48 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 168 0xc42000ee48 principal evaluation fails
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 169 0xc42000ee48 gate 1525348601346256695 evaluation fails
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 16a Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/MyFakeOrg/Admins
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 16b == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/MyFakeOrg/Admins
2018-05-03 11:56:41.346 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 16c Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ MyFakeOrg.Admins ]
2018-05-03 11:56:41.347 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 16d Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
2018-05-03 11:56:41.347 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 16e == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
```

And all the relevant configuration files:

configtx.yaml:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    MyFakeOrgGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *MyFakeOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            ABCDConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *MyFakeOrg

    Channel1:
        Consortium: ABCDConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *MyFakeOrg

    Channel2:
        Consortium: ABCDConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *MyFakeOrg

################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &MyFakeOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: MyFakeOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: MyFakeOrgMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/msp


################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: kafka 

    Addresses:
        - orderer.myfakeorg.si:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 4s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 1000

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 4096 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - kafka0:9092
            - kafka1:9092
            - kafka2:9092
            - kafka3:9092
    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:
        - *MyFakeOrg

Capabilities:
    Global: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_1: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
```

crypto-config.yaml:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: MyFakeOrg
    Domain: myfakeorg.si
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: MyFakeOrg
    Domain: myfakeorg.si
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
    # configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
    #
    # Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
    #   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
    #   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
    #                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
    #
    #                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
    #
    #                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
    #                 Org.Domain, respectively.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Specs:
    #   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.org1.example.com"
    #     CommonName: foo27.org5.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
    #   - Hostname: bar
    #   - Hostname: baz
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Template"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Allows for the definition of 1 or more hosts that are created sequentially
    # from a template. By default, this looks like "peer%d" from 0 to Count-1.
    # You may override the number of nodes (Count), the starting index (Start)
    # or the template used to construct the name (Hostname).
    #
    # Note: Template and Specs are not mutually exclusive.  You may define both
    # sections and the aggregate nodes will be created for you.  Take care with
    # name collisions
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Template:
      Count: 1
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 0
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: hledger-myfakeorg

services:
  ca.myfakeorg.si:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.myfakeorg.si
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.myfakeorg.si-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/32fb492956436eec46d18b2381c3c42ff55c0fd78516c1e3674d18bd0febedc7_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.myfakeorg.si
    networks:
      - default

  orderer.myfakeorg.si:
    container_name: orderer.myfakeorg.si
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=MyFakeOrgMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./../channel-artifacts/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/orderers/orderer.myfakeorg.si/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer

        - ./../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/peers/peer0.myfakeorg.si/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer0
    networks:
      - default

  peer0.myfakeorg.si:
    container_name: peer0.myfakeorg.si
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.myfakeorg.si
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MyFakeOrgMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.myfakeorg.si:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_default
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/peers/peer0.myfakeorg.si/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./../channel-artifacts/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.myfakeorg.si
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - default

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.7
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - default

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.1.0
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.myfakeorg.si:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MyFakeOrgMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/myfakeorg.si/users/Admin@myfakeorg.si/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./../crypto-config/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel-artifacts
    networks:
        - default
    #depends_on:
    #  - orderer.myfakeorg.si
    #  - peer0.myfakeorg.si
    #  - couchdb
```

kafka-compose-base.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

    zookeeper:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
        ports:
            - 2181
            - 2888
            - 3888

    kafka:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
        environment:
            - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
            - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
            - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
            - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=2
            - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
        ports:
            - 9092
```

kafka-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: hledger-myfakeorg


services:

    zookeeper0:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper0
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=1
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
        networks:
            - default
    zookeeper1:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper1
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=2
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
        networks:
            - default

    zookeeper2:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper2
        environment:
            - ZOO_MY_ID=3
            - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2:2888:3888
        networks:
            - default

    kafka0:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: kafka
        container_name: kafka0
        environment:
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        networks:
            - default
    kafka1:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: kafka
        container_name: kafka1
        environment:
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        networks:
            - default
    kafka2:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: kafka
        container_name: kafka2
        environment:
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=2
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        networks:
            - default

    kafka3:
        extends:
            file: kafka-compose-base.yml
            service: kafka
        container_name: kafka3
        environment:
            - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=3
            - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0:2181,zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper0
            - zookeeper1
            - zookeeper2
        networks:
            - default
```

There are two specifics I can think of regarding this network.

- There is only one "organization", or rather, the peer and the orderer organizations are one and the same (the cryptographic material is seemingly still generated twice).
- There's no anchor peers declared for the channels. This feature, as far as I understand it, is intended for cross-org communication, which isn't necessary in this case.

Is any of these two architectural decisions possibly the cause for my problem? Or is there some other technical issue? A similar configuration worked in "solo" mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's some issue with your admin certificate as upon decoding the certificate, it is clear that the admin certificate, that you're using to create the channel, is signed by some other CA (ca.lucis.si, lucis.si) not known by the ordering service and the other components and hence it is throwing error saying certificate signed by unknown authority. As the channel creation is done via a transaction through one of the system chaincodes, the identity of the transaction submitter is validated and the identity certificate should be signed by a registered certificate authority and in your case, the certificate you're providing is issued/signed by an unregistered certificate authority. That's why you can't actually create a channel.

You can decode any pem encoded certificate to see who has signed this certificate by using an online decoder such as [This Online Cert Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html). Just paste your pem encoded certificate there and you'll see the signing information which confirms that the issuer ca is unknown to your network leading to failure in channel creation.

Comment: That's actually the correct domain name however, I merely replaced my company name in the configuration files as not to unnecessarily expose it. So the docker hostname of the ca would indeed be ca.lucis.si. As far as i understand however, I should add the public component the key used to sign these on the CA container to accepted root CAs on all the containers?