# Hyperledger Fabric channel creation failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running the following steps:

1. cryptogen generate --config./crypto-config.yaml
2. export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
   mkdir channel-artifacts
   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
3. configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID "mychannel"

   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID "mychannel" -asOrg Org1MSP

   configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID "mychannel" -asOrg Org2MSP
4. docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
5. docker exec -it cli bash
   ORDERER_CA=/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
   PEER0_ORG1_CA=/work/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
   PEER0_ORG2_CA=/work/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt

   CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP"
   CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
   CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp

   CHANNEL="mychannel"
   CC_SRC_PATH="/chaincode/"

   **peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL -f /work/channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA**

Creating the channel yields:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /work/channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
2018-12-21 05:58:02.995 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2018-12-21 05:58:02.996 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 002 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2018-12-21 05:58:02.996 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 003 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2018-12-21 05:58:02.997 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2018-12-21 05:58:02.998 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 005 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2018-12-21 05:58:02.998 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 006 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security setting to int 256
2018-12-21 05:58:02.998 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 007 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2018-12-21 05:58:02.998 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 008 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2018-12-21 05:58:02.999 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 009 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string
2018-12-21 05:58:02.999 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00a Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2018-12-21 05:58:03.000 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00b Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.000 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00c Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.001 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00d Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2018-12-21 05:58:03.002 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00e Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.003 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00f Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.003 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 010 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.004 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 011 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.005 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 012 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.006 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 013 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.007 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 014 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.007 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 015 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.008 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 016 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.009 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash setting to <nil> <nil>
2018-12-21 05:58:03.010 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2018-12-21 05:58:03.010 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2018-12-21 05:58:03.011 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[SW:map[Hash:SHA2 Security:256 FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:]] PKCS11:map[Hash:<nil> Security:<nil> FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>] Library:<nil> Label:<nil> Pin:<nil>] Default:SW]]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.020 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore]...done
2018-12-21 05:58:03.023 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.024 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts
2018-12-21 05:58:03.041 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@example.com-cert.pem
2018-12-21 05:58:03.049 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/cacerts
2018-12-21 05:58:03.058 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.example.com-cert.pem
2018-12-21 05:58:03.062 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/admincerts
2018-12-21 05:58:03.067 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Inspecting file /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/admincerts/Admin@example.com-cert.pem
2018-12-21 05:58:03.071 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 023 Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/intermediatecerts
2018-12-21 05:58:03.075 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 024 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.075 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlscacerts
2018-12-21 05:58:03.082 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Inspecting file /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
2018-12-21 05:58:03.085 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 027 Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2018-12-21 05:58:03.086 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 028 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.086 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 029 Reading directory /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/crls
2018-12-21 05:58:03.088 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a crls folder not found at [/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.089 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02b MSP configuration file not found at [/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.092 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02c Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2018-12-21 05:58:03.093 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02d Creating Cache-MSP instance
2018-12-21 05:58:03.093 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02e Created new local MSP
2018-12-21 05:58:03.095 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02f Setting up MSP instance OrdererMSP
2018-12-21 05:58:03.096 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2018-12-21 05:58:03.098 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 031 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2018-12-21 05:58:03.127 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 032 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2018-12-21 05:58:03.136 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 033 Loading private key [f402b6fb650fc38fb9a4ae8b21abe98abbc3bf1786186fbc52a4fcf4e0cadeec] at [/work/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore/f402b6fb650fc38fb9a4ae8b21abe98abbc3bf1786186fbc52a4fcf4e0cadeec_sk]...
2018-12-21 05:58:03.143 UTC [msp/identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 034 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2018-12-21 05:58:03.143 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2028-12-18 05:51:00 +0000 UTC
2018-12-21 05:58:03.143 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP OrdererMSP validating identity
2018-12-21 05:58:03.144 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 037 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-12-21 05:58:03.152 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 parsed scheme: ""
2018-12-21 05:58:03.155 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 039 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2018-12-21 05:58:03.156 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03a ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.157 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2018-12-21 05:58:03.158 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4202a1a30, CONNECTING
2018-12-21 05:58:03.179 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03d pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4202a1a30, READY
2018-12-21 05:58:03.183 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 03e Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-12-21 05:58:03.192 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 03f Obtaining default signing identity
2018-12-21 05:58:03.193 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-12-21 05:58:03.193 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 041 Sign: plaintext: 0A90060A0A4F7264657265724D535012...53616D706C65436F6E736F727469756D
2018-12-21 05:58:03.194 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 042 Sign: digest: 92BB1016BFDAC4274F151AA23E3A16A90E71F4D7BBEC266CDC566B398D1DC25B
2018-12-21 05:58:03.195 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 043 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-12-21 05:58:03.195 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 044 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-12-21 05:58:03.196 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 045 Sign: plaintext: 0AC7060A1508021A0608EB81F2E00522...060A56072CF60B8F5697E4ED67FD0157
2018-12-21 05:58:03.198 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 046 Sign: digest: F0D279F148EC9853919A36DED749B885E48E562B9450E6ED02F2D5B8CF42B47A
2018-12-21 05:58:03.211 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 047 parsed scheme: ""
2018-12-21 05:58:03.212 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 048 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2018-12-21 05:58:03.212 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 049 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.example.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2018-12-21 05:58:03.212 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 04a ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2018-12-21 05:58:03.212 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420486a60, CONNECTING
2018-12-21 05:58:03.226 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420486a60, READY
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

I use the following `crypto-config.yaml`

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: false
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: false
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

and this `configtx.yaml`:

```
---
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg

        ID: OrdererMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP

        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP

        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true

    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true

    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_3: true
        V1_2: false
        V1_1: false

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    BatchTimeout: 2s

    BatchSize:

        MaxMessageCount: 10

        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

My `docker-compose-cli.yaml` file:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
        #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/work/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/work/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/work/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/work/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts:/work/channel-artifacts
      - ./crypto-config:/work/crypto-config
      - ./scripts:/work/
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Someone faced a similiar problem?

## Update

Starting first to `orderer` service and then `peer0` gives the following log:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up peer0.org1.example.com
Starting peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Attaching to peer0.org1.example.com
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.355 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
peer0.org1.example.com    |  Version: 1.3.0
peer0.org1.example.com    |  Commit SHA: ab0a67a
peer0.org1.example.com    |  Go version: go1.10.4
peer0.org1.example.com    |  OS/Arch: linux/amd64
peer0.org1.example.com    |  Experimental features: false
peer0.org1.example.com    |  Chaincode:
peer0.org1.example.com    |   Base Image Version: 0.4.13
peer0.org1.example.com    |   Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
peer0.org1.example.com    |   Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
peer0.org1.example.com    |   Docker Namespace: hyperledger
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.355 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.355 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.466 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.485 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 005 ledger mgmt initialized
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.485 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 006 Auto-detected peer address: 172.26.0.3:7051
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.486 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 007 Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.486 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 008 Auto-detected peer address: 172.26.0.3:7051
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.486 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 009 Returning peer0.org1.example.com:7051
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.487 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 00a Starting peer with TLS enabled
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.487 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00b Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org1.example.com
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.488 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 00c Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7052
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.488 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> WARN 00d peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer0.org1.example.com:7052
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.490 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 00e system chaincode lscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) registered
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.490 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 00f system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.490 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 010 system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) registered
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.490 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 011 system chaincode +lifecycle(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lifecycle) registered
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.492 UTC [gossip/service] func1 -> INFO 012 Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0.org1.example.com:7051 and bootstrap set [peer1.org1.example.com:7051]
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.494 UTC [gossip/gossip] NewGossipService -> INFO 013 Creating gossip service with self membership of {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 [] [132 133 191 71 241 248 154 220 155 96 230 124 237 186 150 131 247 243 69 99 70 223 16 116 157 162 26 216 63 117 58 153] peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil> <nil>}
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.495 UTC [gossip/gossip] start -> INFO 014 Gossip instance peer0.org1.example.com:7051 started
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2018-12-21 07:22:09.495 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 015 system chaincode lscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
peer0.org1.example.com    | fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
peer0.org1.example.com    | [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7fd604040259]
peer0.org1.example.com    | 
peer0.org1.example.com    | runtime stack:
peer0.org1.example.com    | runtime.throw(0x111434c, 0x2a)
peer0.org1.example.com    |     /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81
peer0.org1.example.com    | runtime.sigpanic()
peer0.org1.example.com    |     /opt/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:372 +0x28e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a general error which occurs in fabric. I remember getting `BAD Request`
error on subsequent execution of `peer channel create` command when the first one took a bit longer and the request got timed out. However, in this case, the error says that the channel create request is not able to satisfy the implicit policy - i.e., doesn't have appropriate permissions to execute the command. Try setting the msp path in the peer to admin folder, using `export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=<path to admin msp>`, such that peer signs the channel create command with admincerts instead of peer certificates. Here is an useful link explaining the issue in detail - [peer channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726536/peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric)

Comment: looks like there is another problem, I updated my question

Comment: can you check by restarting the peer and Orderer node..i.e, stop the peer and remove the production directory and the start it. Do you have docker or binary implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Checked each container log files, paths were incorrect - adjusting peer template to 2 fixed it