# Failed creating channel in Hyperledger Fabric (permission denied)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I configured manually a Hyperledger Fabric environment using the binary files (without using Docker or fabric samples scripts). I deployed successfully 1 orderer node and 2 peers node (one peer per org), but fails creating the channel.
I used crytogen for crypto material  and cryptotxgen to create the genesis block and the channel transaction.

**Orderer Logs:**

```
2019-01-06 19:01:05.601 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 176 0xc0001b8ea0 gate 1546801265601901160 evaluation starts
2019-01-06 19:01:05.601 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 177 0xc0001b8ea0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2019-01-06 19:01:05.601 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 178 0xc0001b8ea0 processing identity 0 with bytes of ebff60
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 179 0xc0001b8ea0 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected OrdererMSP, got TheChainMSP)
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 17a 0xc0001b8ea0 principal evaluation fails
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 17b 0xc0001b8ea0 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 17c 0xc0001b8ea0 processing identity 0 with bytes of ebff60
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 17d 0xc0001b8ea0 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected OrdererMSP, got TheChainMSP)
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 17e 0xc0001b8ea0 principal evaluation fails
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 17f 0xc0001b8ea0 gate 1546801265601901160 evaluation fails
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 180 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererTheChain/Writers
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 181 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererTheChain/Writers
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 182 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ OrdererTheChain.Writers ]
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 183 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 184 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 185 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Consortiums.Writers Orderer.Writers ]
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 186 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Writers
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 187 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 188 [channel: privatechannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 127.0.0.1:53992 because of error: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 189 Closing Broadcast stream
2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 18a streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-01-06T19:01:05.599Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Broadcast", "grpc.peer_address": "127.0.0.1:53992", "grpc.code": "OK", "grpc.call_duration": "3.042122ms"}
2019-01-06 19:01:05.605 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 18b Error reading from 127.0.0.1:53988: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-01-06 19:01:05.605 UTC [grpc] warningf -> DEBU 18c transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 127.0.0.1:7050->127.0.0.1:53992: read: connection reset by peer
2019-01-06 19:01:05.605 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 18d Closing Deliver stream
2019-01-06 19:01:05.605 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 18f transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2019-01-06 19:01:05.605 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 18e streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-01-06T19:01:05.599Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "127.0.0.1:53988", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "6.48536ms"}
2019-01-06 19:01:05.605 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 190 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

**peer channel create Logs:**

```
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2029-01-03 00:49:00 +0000 UTC
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP TheChainMSP validating identity
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 037 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 parsed scheme:""
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 039 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03a ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{localhost:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-01-06 19:21:13.795 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-01-06 19:21:13.796 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00032a490, CONNECTING
2019-01-06 19:21:13.798 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03d pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00032a490, READY
2019-01-06 19:21:13.798 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 03e Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-01-06 19:21:13.799 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 03f Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 041 Sign: plaintext: 0A96060A0B546865436861696E4D5350...53616D706C65436F6E736F727469756D
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 042 Sign: digest: EDB773D3B4483F960DA91D9CE5E21CA9F0512B808C9AE15B56B2CB1CE663B494
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 043 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 044 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 045 Sign: plaintext: 0AD2060A1A08021A0608A9AAC9E10522...898F89F93F5DEF87555ED63A455E5CFF
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 046 Sign: digest: BAA15E471F224FBF378D144154CF6B126823800A73EF3F9122CB30888C69645F
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 047 parsed scheme: ""
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 048 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 049 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{localhost:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 04a ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-01-06 19:21:13.800 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000242cc0, CONNECTING
2019-01-06 19:21:13.801 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000242cc0, READY
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
```

Im not using TLS

My server is ubuntu 16.04, im using Hyperledger Fabric v1.4 release 2 (20 dec). I tried creating new crypto material and modify the configtx.yaml file, but no ones worked, i get the same error.

**crypto-config.yaml:**

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: thechain.tech
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: AirMed Foundation
    Domain: airmedfoundation.tech
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 3
  - Name: The Chain
    Domain: thechain.tech
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 3
```

**configtxgen.yaml:**

```
---

Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.3.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.3.0 or later.
        V1_3: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: true
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false


Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererTheChain
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: /home/medical/fabric/crypto-material/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/thechain.tech/orderers/orderer.thechain.tech/msp
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin', 'OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin', 'OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &TheChainOrg
        Name: TheChain
        ID: TheChainMSP
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: 127.0.0.1
            Port: 7051
        MSPDir: /home/medical/fabric/crypto-material/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/thechain.tech/users/Admin@thechain.tech/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TheChainMSP.admin', 'TheChainMSP.peer', 'TheChainMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TheChainMSP.admin', 'TheChainMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('TheChainMSP.admin')"

    - &AirMedFoundationOrg
        Name: AirMedFoundation
        ID: AirMedFoundationMSP
        AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: 127.0.0.1
            Port: 17051
        MSPDir: /home/medical/fabric/crypto-material/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/airmedfoundation.tech/users/Admin@airmedfoundation.tech/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirMedFoundationMSP.admin', 'AirMedFoundationMSP.peer', 'AirMedFoundationMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirMedFoundationMSP.admin', 'AirMedFoundationMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirMedFoundationMSP.admin')"

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start.
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka".
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - localhost:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch.
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block.
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a
        # batch.
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. If the "kafka" OrdererType is
        # selected, set 'message.max.bytes' and 'replica.fetch.max.bytes' on the
        # Kafka brokers to a value that is larger than this one.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the
        # preferred max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max
        # bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Max Channels is the maximum number of channels to allow on the ordering
    # network. When set to 0, this implies no maximum number of channels.
    MaxChannels: 0

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects. Edit
        # this list to identify the brokers of the ordering service.
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation.
        Brokers:
            - kafka0:9092
            - kafka1:9092
            - kafka2:9092
            - kafka3:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network.
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

    # Capabilities describes the orderer level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities


Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"


    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities


Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *TheChainOrg
                    - *AirMedFoundationOrg
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *TheChainOrg
                - *AirMedFoundationOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I found this question that have a similar problem
[peer channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726536/peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric), i tried his solution and nothing change. I think the problem is for policy problems and my peers are not sign the transaction with the correct credentials, but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Orderer logs:
`2019-01-06 19:01:05.602 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 185 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Consortiums.Writers Orderer.Writers` ]

Peerlogs:

Error: `got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied`

Its clearly stating that you are not authorize to create a channel

**Why**:
Hyperledger fabric is designed in a secure way 
For every operation, you need a valid Authorization and Authentication

**How**:
Please add admin credentials of majority orgs while creating the channel

**Tips**:
If you use CLI then add admin private key and certificate while creating the channel.

**Help**: If you need more details feel free to comment here iam more than happy to help

Comment: how to create admin credentials with fabric-go-sdk

Comment: so you want to register + enroll admin with go-sdk ?