# Error validating channel creation transaction for new channel creation at a Hyperledger Fabric Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

## Background

I am trying to finish the [Fabric CA Operations Guide](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html) tutorial in order to better understand the details of a TLS setup. However, I am stuck at the [Create and Join Channel](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html#create-and-join-channel) part.

A similar question was asked here at [peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726536/peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric), but sometimes the same errors can have different causes.

I followed the instructions at the aforementioned solution without success. The error I keep getting when I try to create the channel is:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

### Environment

My versions for Docker images are:

- Docker engine version: 19.03.8;
- Docker CA image and version: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4.6;
- Docker Peer image and version: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.0;
- Docker Orderer image and version: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.0;
- Docker Tools (CLI) image and version: hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.0.

### Reproducing the error

> I created a repository at GitHub where I put the codes referenced by the links: [fabric-ca-operations-guide](https://github.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide).

1. I start by executing `tearup-docker-cas.sh` to create all the Docker images for the CAs and consequently the directory structures at */tmp/hyperledger/*:

   `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide/master/tearup-docker-cas.sh | bash -s`
2. When I check that every image is up and running by issuing the command `docker ps` I create the crypto material using `setup-crypto.sh`:

   `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide/master/setup-crypto.sh | bash -s`
3. Then I download the *configtx.yaml* file to my current directory:

   `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide/master/configtx.yaml -o ./configtx.yaml`
4. Now I am ready to set the environment variable *FABRIC_CFG_PATH* so that I can create the genesis block and channel transaction by the `create_genesis_block_channel_tx.sh` script. The artifacts will be available at */tmp/hyperledger/org0/orderer/*:

   `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide/master/create_genesis_block_channel_tx.sh | bash -s`
5. Since the genesis block is available, now we can create the orderer image using `tearup-docker-peers.sh`. This script also creates all the peers and cli containers tools:

   `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide/master/tearup-docker-peers.sh | bash -s`

After the **step 5** I am ready to create the channel. Therefore I use the following command to use the **cli-org1** container:

```
docker exec -it cli-org1 bash -c "export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin/msp; peer channel create -c mychannel -f /tmp/hyperledger/assets/mychannel.tx -o orderer1-org0:7050 --outputBlock /tmp/hyperledger/assets/mychannel.block --tls --cafile /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem"
```

At this point I get the error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

When I want to clean up everything for a fresh start I just execute:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanesbarbosa/fabric-ca-operations-guide/master/teardown-docker.sh | bash -s`

### Fixing Attempts

- I always try a new attempt with a fresh set of crypto materials and images, so I always run the step 6 from the **Reproducing the error** section before trying again;
- I create the channel at the **step 4** as the admin of the organization;
- I make sure the orderer has the TLS root signing certificate listed (everybody is using the same CA for TLS certs);
- The environment variable ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL is set to "debug" at the orderer image, so that I can have more detailed errors;
- I tried to sign the channel creation transaction (**mychannel.tx**) before issuing the command `peer channel create` to make sure it was not a lack of signature, but the error mentions a **/Channel/Application** group policy, that in this case is an Implicit Meta type, where the rule is **"ANY Admins"**;

```
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>

    Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
```

Comment: Hi Hanes, that error clearly suggests that you are using an identity which is not an admin to issue the channel creation. I would check the contents of /tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin/msp. Decode certificates in that folder (openssl x509 -in /route/to.crt -text -noout), in particular signcerts contents, and if you have several certs placed in that folder, would be a good idea to recreate the network deleting all that content first.

Comment: Hi @jfc, thanks for the help!

I checked the identity of the cert before for the admin of org1 at *.../org1/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem*. This is the same cert registered as one of the admins for org1 at *.../org1/msp/admincerts/org1-admin-cert.pem*.

The CA issuer of org1's admin cert is **rca-org1**. Therefore, for the **admin-org1** to be recognized, I need to have the **rca-org1** root certificate inside the orderer at the *.../org0/orderer/msp/cacerts/* directory. I have put this certificate. Am I missing something?